# Converting String Type to Currency in C#

Tags: c#, math, console, type-conversion

I am trying to take the string input of TR and string PMP convert them into currency then multiply together to get an output in USD currency .

```
       string SP;  // Sales Price

       string TR;  //Total Revenue

       string PMP; //Property management percentage

       string PMF; //Property Management Monthly Fee


       Console.WriteLine("What is the total rent revenue?");
       TR = Console.ReadLine();
       Console.WriteLine("what is the percentage you pay to property managment?");
       PMP = Console.ReadLine();
       Console.WriteLine("you will be buying {0}", PMF );


        SP = Console.ReadLine();
        TR = Console.ReadLine();
        PMP = Console.ReadLine();
        PMF = string.Format("{TR:C,PMP:C}") <------- THIS IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO CONVERT AND MULTIPLY****
```

Any help will be grateful. Thank you

PS I am not a programmer by trade (mostly Networking Engineering and Server Admin), This is my first 20 hours into programming.

Comment: Consider using idetifiers like `salesPrice`, `totalRevenue` etc. instead of `SP`, `TR`.

Comment: Please, this seems to be your second question doing this. Get and read a good book. Programming is a craft, you cannot just open an editor and learn it without a good guide. This site is not a tutorial site. It's for specific question. Your question needs a book to answer. A good beginners book. That is no shame, we all started there.

Comment: fair enough. any recommendations on a book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me, I would start by creating a method to get a valid decimal number from the user (because we do this several times, and it should have some error handling for cases when the user enters invalid entries). Something like:

```
public static decimal GetDecimalFromUser(string prompt,
    string errorMessage = "Invalid entry. Please try again.")
{
    decimal value;

    while (true)
    {
        if (prompt != null) Console.Write(prompt);
        if (decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value)) break;
        if (errorMessage != null) Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
    }

    return value;
}
```

Then, I would call this method to get the input from the user, do the required calculation (you didn't specify a formula, so I'm improvising), and output the value to the user:

```
decimal totalRevenue = GetDecimalFromUser("Enter the monthly rent revenue: $");
decimal propMgmtPct = GetDecimalFromUser("Enter the percentage you pay " +
    "for property management: ");
decimal propMgmtFee = totalRevenue * propMgmtPct;

Console.WriteLine("The monthly property management fee will be: {0}",
    propMgmtFee.ToString("C2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The `Format` syntax is more like `string.Format("{0:C},{1:C}", TR, PMP)`.
2. You can only format numeric types such as `decimal` like that. Consider `decimal.TryParse` to see if what the user typed, looks like a number, then format the resulting number.
3. For multiplication you certainly need numeric types, like `decimal`, and you use the asterisk symbol `*` as the multiplication operator.